# How do I choose a specific cursor from a cursor theme I've installed? Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: gnome, mouse, themes, cursor

How do I choose a specific cursor from a cursor theme I've installed?
I've installed Volantes Light Cursors. I am working in Tweaks. In fact, there are numerous other cursors within each of the other installed themes, but I can't find out via internet how/where to choose a specific cursor. TONS of articles on installing themes - can't find anything about choosing a particular one of the specific cursors. Thank you.